Why does the Torah continuously seperate "Geirem" from the rest of Klal Yisrael?
Throughout last week's Parshas - Parshas Acharei Mos - it states a Halacha, then it says that every Jew should keep it, and then adds every Ger (convert).
For example: פרק יז:ח

וַאֲלֵהֶ֣ם תֹּאמַ֔ר אִ֥ישׁ אִישׁ֙ מִבֵּ֣ית יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל וּמִן־הַגֵּ֖ר אֲשֶׁר־יָג֣וּר בְּתוֹכָ֑ם אֲשֶׁר־יַעֲלֶ֥ה עֹלָ֖ה אוֹ־זָֽבַח׃
Say to them further: If anyone of the house of Israel or of the
strangers who reside among them offers a burnt offering or a
sacrifice,

פרק יז:י

וְאִ֨ישׁ אִ֜ישׁ מִבֵּ֣ית יִשְׂרָאֵ֗ל וּמִן־הַגֵּר֙ הַגָּ֣ר בְּתוֹכָ֔ם אֲשֶׁ֥ר יֹאכַ֖ל כׇּל־דָּ֑ם וְנָתַתִּ֣י פָנַ֗י בַּנֶּ֙פֶשׁ֙ הָאֹכֶ֣לֶת אֶת־הַדָּ֔ם וְהִכְרַתִּ֥י אֹתָ֖הּ מִקֶּ֥רֶב עַמָּֽהּ׃
And if anyone of the house of Israel or of the strangers who reside
among them partakes of any blood, I will set My face against the
person who partakes of the blood; I will cut that person off from
among kin.

פרק יז:יב

עַל־כֵּ֤ן אָמַ֙רְתִּי֙ לִבְנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל כׇּל־נֶ֥פֶשׁ מִכֶּ֖ם לֹא־תֹ֣אכַל דָּ֑ם וְהַגֵּ֛ר הַגָּ֥ר בְּתוֹכְכֶ֖ם לֹא־יֹ֥אכַל דָּֽם׃
Therefore I say to the Israelite people: No person among you shall
partake of blood, nor shall the stranger who resides among you partake
of blood.

פרק יז:יג

וְאִ֨ישׁ אִ֜ישׁ מִבְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֗ל וּמִן־הַגֵּר֙ הַגָּ֣ר בְּתוֹכָ֔ם אֲשֶׁ֨ר יָצ֜וּד צֵ֥יד חַיָּ֛ה אוֹ־ע֖וֹף אֲשֶׁ֣ר יֵאָכֵ֑ל וְשָׁפַךְ֙ אֶת־דָּמ֔וֹ וְכִסָּ֖הוּ בֶּעָפָֽר׃
And if any Israelite or any stranger who resides among them hunts down
an animal or a bird that may be eaten, that person shall pour out its
blood and cover it with earth.

פרק יז:טו
וְכׇל־נֶ֗פֶשׁ אֲשֶׁ֨ר תֹּאכַ֤ל נְבֵלָה֙ וּטְרֵפָ֔ה בָּאֶזְרָ֖ח וּבַגֵּ֑ר וְכִבֶּ֨ס בְּגָדָ֜יו וְרָחַ֥ץ בַּמַּ֛יִם וְטָמֵ֥א עַד־הָעֶ֖רֶב וְטָהֵֽר׃

Any person, whether citizen or stranger, who eats what has died or has
been torn by beasts shall wash those clothes, bathe in water, remain
impure until evening—and shall then be pure.

My question is: What is the reason for the Torah specifically mentioning converts seperately?

None of those translations say "convert"

The Torah does the opposite of separating the geir but continuously emphasizes the halacha is the same even in cases which one would logically think it would be different such as during pesach

It is clear that גֵּר (ger) as used in the Torah does not mean convert. The use of the word ger to mean convert is a post-biblical usage

@DoubleAA - it is reffering to a stranger in Klal Yisroel (aka a convert

@Shalom can you support that claim?

@DoubleAA - what else can it be reffering to?

@DoubleAA???????

Different meforshim seem to give different explanations for each time the ger is specified. It does seem that most of the rishonim and acharonim that I saw do understand it to mean "convert"
